# Put request into Spring Boot Controller

Tags: ajax, spring-boot

Im trying to send a json string with ajax to my spring boot controller but i keep getting the error net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS, and there are a bunch of $csrfError after the url. I've looked at tons of other websites and questions but I still can't get it to work. how do i correctly setup my ajax request so that my controller will accept the data?

ive already tried changing the method type to post and changing the RequestParams to ResponseBody but i went back to RequestParams

```
my ajax function
function deleteEvent() {
        var startTime = document.getElementById('newStartTime').value;
        var endTime = document.getElementById('newEndTime').value;
        var type = document.getElementById('newTimeOffType').value;
        var search = {startTime: startTime, endTime: endTime, type: type};
        if(confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this event?")){
            $.ajax({
                method: 'PUT',
                contentType: 'application/json',
                url: '/vacation/deleteEvents',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: JSON.stringify(search),
                success: function () {
                    console.log('success');
                },
                error: function (e) {
                    console.log(e);
                }
            })
        }
        else {
            alert('you said no')
        }
```

my spring controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/vacation/deleteEvents", method=RequestMethod.PUT)
@ResponseBody
public String deleteCalendarEvents(@RequestParam String startTime, @RequestParam String endTime, @RequestParam String type, HttpSession session ){
    User user = (User) session.getAttribute("currentUser");
    System.out.println("startTime: " + startTime);
    System.out.println("endTime: " + endTime);
    System.out.println("type: " + type);
    return null;
}
```

i want it to print out the starttime, endtime, and type into my console but i keep getting this error.

Comment: Did you try it by using `postman`? because you can know if `backend` fails.

Comment: If you are not expecting to return anything why not make it void? The return type is what could cause issue.

Comment: i do not know what postman is so i have not tried it, and the return was originally used to redirect back to the homepage @JonathanJohx

Comment: i try to run the ajax request i get the error net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS, and there are a bunch of $csrfError after the url. @reflexdemon

Comment: When you made the return type as void did you remove the @ResponseBody?

Comment: no i did not remove the ResponseBody. @reflexdemon

Comment: Can you try removing it and give it a go.

Comment: it didnt change anything, i still get the too_many_redirect error @reflexdemon

Comment: Do you have spring Security on your project?